# libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: android, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, android-sdk-tools

I am facing an issue on ubuntu 12.04 as :

> /usr/lib/ndk/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as:
>   error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

But it says

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done lib32z1 is already the newest version. 0
>   upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 610 not upgraded.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 124):

After checking to which package does the libz.so.1 belongs (http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/i386/zlib1g/filelist) you should try to install zlib1g:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g
```

As pointed by @E-rich, it may be required to add a :i386 suffix to the package name for the package manager correctly identify it:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386
```

**EDIT** (for CentOS or other distro that makes use of `yum`):

If someone using CentOS (or any other distro that makes use of `yum`) that may end up reading this question, @syslogic proposed the following solution in the comments:

```
yum install zlib.i686
```

or, for 32-bit binaries:

```
yum install zlib.i386
```

Comment: This worked for me with one minor change: `sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386`

Comment: @Palak `yum install zlib.i686`

Comment: finally after so much search.  
sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386 worked.

Comment: May 2016, install zlib1g:i386 still work with ubuntu 15.10. +1

Comment: Android Studio 2.2.3, Oracle Java 8, Android Build-Tools 23.0.2 in Ubuntu 16.04.1 amd64, this worked for me `sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386`

Comment: Sometimes `libz.so*` get's installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me

> sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5

Comment: For CentOS I needed to install both zlib and libgcc.  
yum install zlib.i686 libgcc

Answer (score 3):

For Fedora (can be useful for someone)

`sudo dnf install zlib-1.2.8-10.fc24.i686 libgcc-6.1.1-2.fc24.i686`

Answer (score 2):

Check below link: 
Specially "Install 32 bit libraries (if you're on 64 bit)"

```
 https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Dev-Install:-Android-on-Linux
```

Comment: this is what finally worked for me "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --yes lib32z1 lib32stdc++6"

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386
fixed the Gradle issue on Android 2.1.1 on Xubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

for centos, just zlib didn't solve the problem.I did 
    `sudo yum install zlib-devel.i686`

Answer (score 1):

For Arch Linux, it is `pacman -S lib32-zlib` from [multilib](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multilib), not `zlib`.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought everyone should know that the videodownloadhelper companion applicaiton installs it's own version of libz.so.1 in /usr/lib at least in Archlinux.  A simple reinstall of zlib, even with --overwrite='*' does not fix the problem.  It actually breaks the kernel and a pacstrap from the recovery media is needed.  Stay away from the vdhcoapp for now...

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

Installing the `lib64z1` package solved it for me: `sudo apt install lib64z1`.

---

#### Backstory:

While using a Raspberry Pi OS VM and trying to connect it to GitHub Actions, the library `libz.so.1` was missing.
This error appeared when I ran the `config.sh` script, more specifically when this script ran `ldd ./bin/libSystem.IO.Compression.Native.so`.

I updated `zlib1g`, `zlib1g-dev` and `zlib1g:i386` with no improvements.

I then noticed that the only `libz.so.1` library installed was 32 bits by doing `sudo find / -name libz.so.1*`, that returned these 2 file locations:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (this one is a symbolic link to the one above)
```

and analysing this library with `file /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11` returned:

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11: ELF 32-bit ...
```

Now that I've found that I was missing the 64-bit version of this library, searching for a package with it was done on the debian packages website: https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bullseye&arch=i386&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libz.so.1 which shows that `lib64z1` has the library we want on the 64 bits library directory: `/usr/lib64/libz.so.1`.

I've also confirmed this package exists on the Ubuntu package repository: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lib64z1

Answer (score -1):

sudo yum install zlib* swig dtc patch bison flex gcc zlib.i686 bc m4 zip unzip ncurses-compat-libs
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libncursesw.so.6 /usr/lib/libtinfo.so.5

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

I've downloaded these packages:

- libc6-i386
- lib32stdc++6
- lib32gcc1
- lib32ncurses5
- zlib1g

I then unpacked them and added the directories to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my `~/.bashrc`. Just make sure to add proper dirs to the path.

Comment: To be honest - I don't know. I just did `find \`pwd\` -type d | xargs | tr " " ":"` to generate a complete listing of all subdirectories. But probably there are docs out there that tell exactly which those are. I was short on time, so I had to guess :-)