# Android Studio 64-bit ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED

Tags: android, android-studio, 64-bit, emulation, ubuntu-14.04

I recently upgraded my ubuntu 13.10 64-bit to 14.04 64-bit. Android Studio always worked well on 13.10.

On 14.04 I had a problem with gradle ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629368/how-to-fix-android-studio-getting-stuck-executing-gradle-tasks)), which was a problem with missing libz.so.1. Following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256866/libz-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file), I had to install the 32-bit version of this package, and it fixed my problem.

Now (I thought it was related), when trying to launch a device emulator, I have this message :

> ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use
>   them you will have to do at least one of the following:
>   - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
>   - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment. Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
>   aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
>   Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.

But my system is 64-bit (and by the way `-force-32bit` trick doesn't work).

Strangely, I removed the 32-bit package I installed, and nothing changed (my gradle problem didn't show up again and my emulator problem is still here).

What should I do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday, I had the same problem after updating my Ubuntu. Today it is fixed in the new update. Just update your Ubuntu and run the emulator after the update. It should work.

Current kernel version after the update is: **3.13.0-61-generic**

Answer (score 3):

I'm also using Ubuntu 14.04, and apparently there is a bug with the new version of the kernel (**3.13.0-59-generic**), since I was working yesterday with the emulators and I didn't have any problems until today, when there was a kernel update.

I rebooted Ubuntu, this time choosing the previous version of the kernel (**3.13.0-58-generic**), and it works again.

I hope this helps.

PS: you can boot the previous versions of the kernel from the grub, on *Advanced options for Ubuntu*.

Comment: Fine !! It works. Thank you very much. Is there a way to automatically boot on this kernel, without having to choose everytime ? If so, what happens in the next kernel release ?

Comment: Glad to know! What I did was to remove the version **3.13.0-59** of the kernel using Synaptic. Doing this, it boots automatically from the **3.13.0-58** version (the previous version). I don't think it's the best practice (the kernel was updated for a reason after all), but it works. What is left, is to report this bug on launchpad.

Answer (score 2):

I have 64 bit Ubuntu with kernel 4.8.0-37 and I could not solve this problem until I explicitly launched the `emulator64-x86` executable instead of just `emulator` that was launched by Android Studio by default.

Answer (score 0):

The 3.13.0-59 kernel was causing the same problem for me after a recent update. I uninstalled it by running:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic
```

When rebooting, grub will automatically use the previous version of the kernel. Note that this also removes the `linux-image-generic` package, preventing future automatic kernel updates.

Comment: I'm not an expert, so if the kernel is released, say with a 3.13.0-60, how will I be notified it is available and how to turn automatic kernel updates back on ?