# android studio on 64 bit OS running 64bit OS give ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

I got similar to this problem: [Android Studio 64-bit ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680018/android-studio-64-bit-error-32-bit-linux-android-emulator-binaries-are-deprecat)

I run android studio 2.1.1 on Gentoo Linux/amd64,
and when I try to run emulator of android android studio give me error:

> /home/user/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full
>   -avd Nexus_5X_API_23 ERROR: 32-bit Linux Android emulator binaries are DEPRECATED, to use them
>          you will have to do at least one of the following:
>          - Use the '-force-32bit' option when invoking 'emulator'.
>          - Set ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT to 'true' in your environment.
>          Either one will allow you to use the 32-bit binaries, but please be
>          aware that these will disappear in a future Android SDK release.
>          Consider moving to a 64-bit Linux system before that happens.

But

> $ file /home/user/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator
>   /home/user/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator: ELF 64-bit LSB executable,
>   x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter
>   /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped

As you can see emulator is 64bit binary, I run it 64bit OS,
also Tools->Android->Avd Manger show that Nexus_5X_API_23 has CPU/ABI = x86_64,

so what is "32-bit error" about?

**Update**

Looks like it need some permission, because of I can run emulator from root user. But still can not guess what exactly it need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with the `SHELL` environment variable.
If I run `emulator` under root with `SHELL=/bin/bash` it all works fine, but if I run `emulator` from an ordinary user with `SHELL=bash`, it fails and shows the error message about 32 bit.

Comment: @AndreyPietrov I set environment variable to right value, as described in answer.