# while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1 : perforce running error

Tags: linux, perforce

i tried to install perforce in Linux.  I encounter the problem showed (error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file ) when i run perforce.
How to fix it?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256866/libz-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file/23454209#23454209