# React Native gets stuck at "Building 61% > :app:mergeDebugResources"

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, build.gradle

I'm trying to run a React-Native android app.

All the required SDK files are downloaded and everything about the dependencies should be fine, but when I hit the `react-native run-android` command it gets stuck at

> "Building 61% > :app:mergeDebugResources"

here is the complete console log:

```
    react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Running /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: no devices/emulators found
Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug...
Starting a new Gradle Daemon for this build (subsequent builds will be faster).
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp30110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(1559605289): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1838692001): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(341786400): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1318881500): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(2031786380): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1712650048): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(536775832): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(558020168): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(2029168255): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1962416436): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1078641575): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(871612259): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(256729263): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1280959212): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1562609003): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(439000834): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(698069606): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1841922512): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(1745052097): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(2080059535): /home/ali/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_15" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_11" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_14" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_8" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_12" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_16" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_6" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_13" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_9" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_10" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_7" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_18" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_17" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_20" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_19" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:104)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:107)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:206)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Building 61% > :app:mergeDebugResources
```

I waited about an hour but nothing happens!

Any contribution to solve this problem will be appreciate.

Comment: tried to cancel and rebuild?

Comment: @dv3 yes even I rebooted but the same thing happened

Comment: check out this question it might help out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256866/libz-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you solved it?

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko I took a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256866/libz-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file, there was some thing wrong with os packages

Comment: In my case it were tempororary files created by Realm Browser in the project root.