# Issue running unit tests with PhantomJS if installed locally

Tags: unit-testing, gulp, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I have an issue running my unit tests in my CI environment (teamcity). My agent throws this issue when I try to run my unit test:

> ERROR [phantomjs.launcher]:
>   /opt/home/teamcity/buildAgent2/work/a6ed2b843575d927/node_modules/karma-phantomjs2-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs2-ext/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs:
>   error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory

I don't have PhantomJS installed globally. It is part of my devDependencies and is installed in a previous build step. I'm using Karma as unit test runner and specified the phantomJS runner like this:

> browsers: ['PhantomJS2']

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256866/libz-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file